# Unable to update taxonomy field value using REST API or JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jsom, taxonomy

I'm not able to modify taxonomy field values with REST API or JSOM for a specific library.
My code works on other lists, but not on this particular library, what can the problem be?

- The library has > 380 000 items.
- Field can be changed via edit item dialog.
- No error messages (REST API or JSOM).
- Field is single value only, so no ["_0"](http://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/update-using-rest-to-update-a-multi-value-taxonomy-field-in-sharepoint)-problem.

  - Have verified there is no `Single_0` (by title) field.
- I want to use `odata=verbose`, but I have tried without it (and removed all the `__metadata` properties), with same result.
- Updating other fields, such as *Title*, works (in same request, both JSOM and REST API).
- I have used edit item dialog to change the value back and forth to verify that the term ID I'm trying to use is without doubt the correct one.
- "Nulling" out the field does not work either (e.g., `{ Single: null }`).
- Have tried hard coding correct `WssId` and `Label`, but no luck.

My REST API-code looks like this:

```
fetch(`${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('TaxonomyTest')/Items(1)`, {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'MERGE',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'x-requestdigest': _spPageContextInfo.formDigestValue,
    'if-match': '*'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    __metadata: {
      type: 'SP.Data.TaxonomyTestListItem'
    },
    Single: {
      __metadata: {
        type: 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue',
      },
      WssId: -1,
      TermGuid: '10114d7f-b240-4b93-a23b-15ce3e5b9bbe'
    }
  })
})
```

And my JSOM-code looks like this:

```
const ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
const item = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TaxonomyTest').getItemById(1)
const value = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue()
value.set_termGuid('10114d7f-b240-4b93-a23b-15ce3e5b9bbe')
value.set_wssId(-1)
item.set_item('Single', value)
item.update()
ctx.executeQueryAsync()
```

I have not tried with CSOM.

## Update

Was just able to update item using JSOM, but with a more correct approach:

```
const ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
const list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TaxonomyTest')
const item = list.getItemById(1)
const field = list.get_fields().getByTitle('Single');
const taxField = clientContext.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
const value = new SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue()
value.set_termGuid('10114d7f-b240-4b93-a23b-15ce3e5b9bbe')
value.set_wssId(-1)
taxField.setFieldValueByValue(item, value);
item.update()
ctx.executeQueryAsync()
```

But still not with REST, but that might not be supported.
**Note:** My previous JSOM code does work on other lists, as well as the REST code. I can't mimic `SetValueByValue` in REST, since it does two method calls (when inspecting `ProcessQuery`, as well as the method is not exposed).